# Vue Resource - Redirecting after post to asp.net core web api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asp.net-core

I have this method on my api:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] IEnumerable<MovieViewModel> moviesViewModel)
{
    var movies = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Movie>>(moviesViewModel).ToList();

    var cup = new Cup(movies);
    cup.Run();

    return CreatedAtRoute("Get", new { id = cup.Id }, cup);
}
```

And I have this function that calls that Post method in my Vue app.

```
$_sendMovies() {
      this.$http.post('https://worldcupapi-gabs.azurewebsites.net/api/cup', this.selectedMovies )
        .then(function (res) {
            console.log(res.status);
            console.log(res.headers.get('location'));
      });
    },
```

The post is ok, it returns 201. But after it, I want to get the `Location` header that contains the URL that I want to use to redirect after the post. However, `res.headers.get('location')` is null and I can't find another way to get it.

Comment: res.headers.get('location') is correct syntax for getting a header value in vue-resource. Have you tried checking the reponse header object using console?

Comment: Your server needs to expose the header by setting the [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) response header - my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52333446/core-2-1-refuses-to-respond-with-access-control-expose-headers/52334208#52334208) shows how.

Comment: Why do you return 201 if you want to redirect ?

Comment: Thanks again @KirkLarkin. If you want, answer the question so I can accept it.

Comment: An answer would be mostly a copy of the one I linked so deleting this question might be the best thing to do now that it’s solved.