# Blazor WebAssembly HttpResponseMessage empty Headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WebAssembly client making POST request to a backend ASP.NET Core API. HttpResponseMessage.Headers is empty.

In Startup.cs I have CORS configuration:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOriginsPolicy",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:5000")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials();
        });
});
```

and later:

```
app.UseCors("AllowAllOriginsPolicy");
```

In Blazor app I'm making POST request:

```
var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(content), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, stringContent);

foreach (var h in result.Headers) // !Headers collection is empty
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{h.Key}:{h.Value}");
}
```

In the controller I return Created() with location url of created resource:

```
return Created($"units/{unit.Id}", unit);
```

Request completes successfully and headers are there:

[image: Chrome dev tools]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Not all headers are exposed to the client. See [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) and [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52334208/2630078) that sets `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin I added .WithExposedHeaders("Location") and it works. Big thanks for a quick reply!